# How could I use the Eloquent ORM when I try to inherit a model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

ENV:
PHP:8.2.0
LARAVEL:10.10

I have a model Message like this:

```
# Message.php

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

class Message extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $timestamps=false;

    function subject():HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Subject::class);
    }
}
```

I have a repository like this:

```
# MessageRepository.php

<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Models\Message;

class MessageRepository
{
    public function __construct(protected Message $Message)
    {
    }
}
```

I have a service like this:

```
# MessageService.php

<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\Repositories\MessageRepository;

class MessageService
{

    function __construct(protected MessageRepository $message)
    {

    }

    function infos()
    {
        return ['count'=>$this->all()->count()];
//        return ['count'=>4];
    }

    function all()
    {
        return $this->message->all();

    }
}
```

When I try to call infos(), I got an error message `Call to undefined method App\Repositories\MessageRepository::all()`

Why I couldn't inherit from Model?
How to fix my code?

One of my solution is define a function `all()` in MessageRepository.php

```
...

    function all()
    {
        return $this->message->all();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `protected` to `public` in MessageRepository.

And the right call method is:

```php
function all() {
    return $this->message->Message->all();
}
```